# Secure code promoting with svn

Tags: svn, optimization, workflow

I'm working with a small development team, which is using subversion as a versioning system.

Currently we have the following workflow Development > Testing > Staging > Production, the first 3 phases use code as a checkout from svn, and coding in branches, production server is working on a exported version of code from trunk, and this is done manually by a QA team, they are the department who upload code to production server.

My question is how to secure this process? A QA member could do an unauthorized change to the code and upload it to production server, how can I avoid this?

May be to change the process somehow to automate the code promotion to production systems?